# Calling subsclass @classmethod from parent class

Tags: python, python-3.x, class-method

I'm trying to do the following:

```
class A:

    @classmethod
    def test_function(cls, message):
      cls.__get_the_function()

class B(A):

    @classmethod
    def __get_the_function(cls):
        return print("BBBB")


class C(A):

    @classmethod
    def __get_the_function(cls):
        return print("CCCC")
```

however when I call:

```
B.test_function("Test")
```

I get the following:

```
AttributeError: type object 'B' has no attribute '_A__get_the_function'
```

I want class `A` to `__get_the_function` from the subclass (either class `B` or `C` depends on which one I use), but it looks like it is trying to look for it in itself.

NOTE: I'm using **Python 3.8.2**

Comment: Prefer a simple `_`-prefixed name to a `__`-prefixed name to avoid name wrangling. Also, it's good practice to provide at least a dummy definition of `_get_the_function` in `A` itself, since `test_function` relies on its existence.

Comment: In other words, it's not because the method is a `classmethod`, it's because of the `__` prefix you added to its name.

Comment: Don't use double-underscores. **Why were you using double-underscores to begin with**? The *only point* is to prevent subclasses from overriding it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`__`-prefixed names are handled specially during class creation. The name is replaced when the function is *defined* by a mangled name, as if you had defined the function as

```
@classmethod
def test_function(cls, message):
    cls._A__get_the_function()
```

in the first place.

This is done to explicitly provide a way to hide a name from a subclass. Since you *want* to override the name, `__get_the_function` isn't an appropriate name; use an ordinary `_`-prefixed name if you want to mark it as private:

```
class A:

    @classmethod
    def test_function(cls, message):
      cls._get_the_function()

    # Define *something*, since test_function assumes it
    # will exist. It doesn't have to *do* anything, though,
    # until you override it.
    @classmethod
    def _get_the_function(cls):
        pass
```